# Collision filtering in Drake - Non-colliding objects with penetration queries

Tags: drake

I am working with a simulated robotic manipulation scenario in pyDrake, and I want to have some non-colliding geometries that I can use to check for certain properties - for example, I placed a box inside a target region and want to check if anything is inside that box after a few seconds of simulation. I want to be able to quickly and easily move and rotate that box around during execution, so applying an explicit check on object positions isn't a good alternative.

I've tried a few approaches using collision filtering (CollisionFilterManager), but have multiple problems related to that.
My main questions are this:

**1) Is there a way to have non-colliding geometry in a Drake MultibodyPlant, where I can still check some form of penetration or SDF distance between it and other bodies in the scene?**

---

The simplest way I thought of is to apply a collision filter for that geometry (CollisionFilterManager) and then just check the SDF between that box and relevant objects using the MultibodyPlant's geometry query port, something like:

```
### Assemble system with a MultibodyPlant and SceneGraph, add relevant models, extract body poses
#geometry_set_all - a GeometrySet object with the BodyIndex's of all bodies in the plant

#Make box non-colliding
box_exclude_declaration = CollisionFilterDeclaration().ExcludeBetween(GeometrySet(box_id), geometry_set_all)
box_exlcude_filter_ID = scene_graph.collision_filter_manager().ApplyTransient(box_exclude_declaration)

### Set up visualization, build diagram, run simulation

#Create query object to check penetration with geometry
query_object = plant.get_geometry_query_input_port().Eval(plant_context)
penetrating_pairs = query_object.ComputePointPairPenetration()
```

Which did not work. It seems applying the filter to the box for collisions also applies it for point pair penetration (I'd run simulations, objects would be inside the box, but the box would not be included in penetrating_pairs)

Next I tried removing the transient filter after simulating, before creating the query_object, with:

`removed = scene_graph.collision_filter_manager().RemoveDeclaration(box_exlcude_filter_ID)`

and even though "removed" is True, "penetrating_pairs" again does not include the box. In fact, resuming simulation shows clearly the box is still filtered out of collisions. I tried adding the filter *after* I built the diagram, and then the box was treated as collision geometry.
**Based on this information, does this mean collision filtering cannot be changed after a diagram is built?**

I am now unsure what to do, short of building two separate systems: one without the box for simulating and one with the box to check collisions, where I transfer object states over from the first simulation.
This seems like a round-about way to do it, and **generally it would be great to easily switch collisions on and off for other applications, like checking if object A collides with anything else, but ignoring if it collides with object B.**

Answer (score 1):

Like Thomas said, collision filtering is done on a per-context basis. However, creating a new context is not required (and quite heavy handed).

Like many other functionalities in SceneGraph, there are two flavors of collision filter managers. There's [one that affects the entire model](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_scene_graph.html#a76a5871dd4432de7e8225f334765729f) and [one that modifies only a single context](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_scene_graph.html#a3d5bf882337dfed524c1da91fb96f618). If you want to turn a particular filter on and off repeatedly in a simulation, you probably want the second version.

Here's some modified pseudocode based on your answer above:

```
builder = DiagramBuilder()
plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, time_step=1e-4)

## Configure the plant ##
# ...

plant.Finalize()
diagram = builder.Build()
diagram_context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext()

scene_graph_context =
    scene_graph.GetMyMutableContextFromRoot(diagram_context)
box_exclude_declaration = CollisionFilterDeclaration().ExcludeBetween(
    GeometrySet(box_id), geometry_set_all
)

## Apply the filter to the particular context used by the simulation ##
scene_graph.collision_filter_manager(scene_graph_context).ApplyTransient(
    box_exclude_declaration
)

simulator = Simulator(diagram, diagram_context)

## Run the sim ##
simulator.AdvanceTo(...)

## Remove the filter  ##
scene_graph.collision_filter_manager(scene_graph_context).RemoveDeclaration(
    box_exlcude_filter_ID
)

## Now do the checks without the filter ##
# ...

## After the check, add the filter back on ##
scene_graph.collision_filter_manager(scene_graph_context).ApplyTransient(
    box_exclude_declaration
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Collision filtering is applied on a per-context basis. So you could create a new context, not apply the collision filtering, set the joint positions to match your old context, and then try to measure the point penetration distance.

Comment: Thanks for the response, contexts are still illusive to me, so I wasn't aware that the same system could have multiple contexts created. I managed to do what I wanted by creating a second context of the diagram after removing the contact filter (see my other answer for skeleton code)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the skeleton for my working code, now able to check collisions and run simulations with separate collision filters:

```
builder = DiagramBuilder()
plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, time_step=1e-4)

## Assemble plant, extract relevant parameters ##

plant.Finalize()
box_exclude_declaration = CollisionFilterDeclaration().ExcludeBetween(GeometrySet(box_id), geometry_set_all)
box_exlcude_filter_ID = scene_graph.collision_filter_manager().ApplyTransient(box_exclude_declaration)

## Build and extract contexts ##

plant_sim_context = plant.GetMyMutableContextFromRoot(diagram_context)

## Run sim  ##

removed = scene_graph.collision_filter_manager().RemoveDeclaration(box_exlcude_filter_ID)
diagram_context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext()
plant_mental_context = plant.GetMyMutableContextFromRoot(diagram_context)
plant_mental_context.SetStateAndParametersFrom(plant_sim_context)
#Now it works to check collisions with this plant_mental_context!
#After any additional simulation with plant_sim_context, repeat the step above to check for collisions again
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one last option. As documented, there is [one distance query](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_query_object.html#a7a66a8b3fc43f34d11a9cd475fb77ee1) that ignores the collision filters: the query between two specific geometries.

If you stored the id(s) of the geometry(ies) being filtered and a set of ids for all of the other geometries you're interested in, you could systematically call the `ComputeSignedDistancePairClosestPoints()` method on the power set. This would be particularly advantageous if you didn't want to know distance to *any* other object, but, instead, were interested in a limited set.